# Update class in PropertyDrawer without using PropertyField or Begin/End Property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Is it possible to update/serialize the values of the underlying class in a `PropertyDrawer` without using `BeginProperty`/`EndProperty` or `PropertyField`?

I am in the process of converting a portion of a `CustomEditor`, which contained editor functionality for the class in question.  I want my class to always use the same editor, but gave up on it a long time ago due to the complexity of converting to a property drawer. There are functions that are used at runtime and in the editor that I would like to avoid duplicating in the `PropertyDrawer` ui.

**Object reference:**

```
var myObject = (MyClass)fieldInfo.GetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject);
```

**Attempt:**

```
// Size Property
//
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, sizeProperty);
if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
{
    var newX = xProperty.intValue;
    var newY = yProperty.intValue;

    myObject.SetSize(newX, newY); // <- "myObject" is the object being drawn by the PropertyDrawer
}
```

I tried moving the function call to inside of `BeginProperty`/`EndProperty` of the class which the property drawer is for, with no change.  This does not update the serialized data, even though I am directly modifying the reference.  It seems like unity rebuilds the serialized data from the `SerializedProperty` objects it creates for the object type.  The function being called manipulates fields of the underlying object (fields being changed do not use `PropertyField` or `BeginProperty`/`EndProperty`).

Is there a way to bypass that mechanism so that my logic does not need to be rewritten in the editor UI?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Update()` on the serialized property resolved the issue.

```
// Size Property
//
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, sizeProperty);
if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
{
    var newX = xProperty.intValue;
    var newY = yProperty.intValue;

    myObject.SetSize(newX, newY);

    property.serializedObject.Update(); // <- Update the underlying object after change
}
```

I had tried this before and it didn't work.  The call to update was made after other property field(s), which may have caused the problem.